# Angular autocomplete encoded api issue

Tags: javascript, angularjs

My api req is like `this http://servername/sdw/v1/users?fields=empname&filter={empname=Adam}`, when I run my code this api req has been encoded only for special characters.

```html
<div angucomplete-alt id="ex5" 
     placeholder="Search Employee" 
     pause="500" 
     selected-object="afterSelectedEmployee" 
     remote-url="http://servername/sdw/v1/users" 
     remote-url-request-formatter="remoteUrlRequestFn" 
     remote-url-data-field="items" 
     title-field="empname" 
     description-field="description" 
     minlength="2" 
     input-class="form-control form-control-small" 
     match-class="highlight">
</div>
```

```js
app.controller('ngAutoCompleteController', ['$scope','$http', function ($scope,$http) {
$scope.Employees=[];
$scope.SelectedEmployee=null;

$scope.afterSelectedEmployee = function (selected) {
    if (selected) {
        $scope.SelectedEmployee = selected.originalObject;
    }
}

$scope.remoteUrlRequestFn = function(str) { 
var urlParam = 'empname&filter={empname=';
urlParam = urlParam+str+'}';   

return {fields: urlParam};
```

Comment: What exactly is the question? I think you need to URL encode the `filter` param. Something like `var urlParam = 'empname&filter=' + encodeURI('{empname=' + str + '}');`

Comment: my question is how to make  my code to  work for this api http://servernamesdw/v1/users?fields=empname&filter={empname=Adam}

Comment: Does `var urlParam = 'empname&filter=' + encodeURI('{empname=' + str + '}');` work?

Comment: No remote-api-handler solved my problem